# Toggling dropdowns using jQuery, with binding and unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

This code is used to toggle some dropdowns. I've added the click event on the document to close the dropdown on click outside, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. I want it to be optimized for better performance.

Let me know if you have a better way to bind/unbind the events.

```
$('.header-top-bar .toggle').each(function (index) {
  var $this = $(this),
      $parent = $this.parent(),
      $dropdown = $this.siblings('.toggle-content');

  $this.on('click.toggle' + index, function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $dropdown.toggleClass('isOpen');

    // Outside
    $document.on('click.toggle' + index, function (event) {
      if (!$(event.target).closest($parent).length) {
        $dropdown.removeClass('isOpen');
        $document.off('click.toggle' + index);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using this code, once the dropdown is closed no more events run.

```
$('.header-top-bar .toggle').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      $content = $this.next('.toggle-content');

  if (!$content.hasClass('isOpen')) {
    $content.addClass('isOpen');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $document.on('click.headerToggle', function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest($content).length) {
          $content.removeClass('isOpen');
          $document.off('click.headerToggle');
        }
      });
    }, 10);
  }
});
```

Thank you all for your help.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/14/)

Comment: Warning: this doen't work at all. See https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/12/.

Comment: @cFreed Was missing the $document var, fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/14/

Answer (score 4):

First, regarding readability, I suggest changing the following names:

- $dropdown -> $content
- .toggle (class) -> .togglable
- .toggle (namespace) -> .toggling
- .isOpen -> isToggleOpen

On the other hand this can be achieved with reduced code (and less internal working impact), with only one event binded:

```
var $togglables = $('.togglable-content');
$(document).on('click.toggling', function (event) {
  var $target = $(event.target),
  $content = $target.siblings('.togglable-content');
  if (!$target.hasClass('isTogglableOpen')) {
    $togglables.not($content).removeClass('isTogglableOpen');
    $content.toggleClass('isTogglableOpen');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here is the [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/11/).

Comment: Very nice answer...

Comment: Or, if you like [one-liners](https://jsfiddle.net/ryy1yr0j/7/) ...

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Oh yes, I retain good ideas: 1) reducing internal work by using `next()` rather than `siblings()`; 2) the trick of toggling involved element first inside of the `not()` definition. On the other hand, I prefer keeping `$toggables` definition outside, to evaluate it only once.

Comment: @cFreed, yes for sure, I'm not sure I would go quite that far in deployed code.

Comment: @cFreed Thanks for your input. I am not sure what has more impact on the dom, but from your answer I see that every time a click happens you run the code to check if the click is on the togglable button. Isn't that worst in terms of performance? On my original code I only bind the click on dom once the togglable is open and unbind it once is closed. I would prefer something more similar to that. Also there's an issue with your code, if you click inside the togglable content it closes. Thanks again.

Comment: @ValeriuTimbuc Yes, in my version any click anywhere will cause the code to run. But it can't at all be an issue, since a click is something user-dependent so it'll never be executed repeatedly at microtime speeds, and hence will not have any impact. In the other hand, regarding the click inside the content, you're perfectly right. So I updated my answer and the associated fiddle.

Comment: @cFreed This is for an admin template, so there will be clicks all the time. Im not sure if this is the best way to go. I would also have to prevent default, so I will have to add another check to your code to see if it's an anchor tag. Following my original code structure, do you have any suggestions to improve the event binding/unbinding for the outside click?

Comment: @ValeriuTimbuc "there will be clicks all the time": I guess this is your response to my "it'll never be executed repeatedly", but I still don't see an issue there. Each click causes more work in my version, yes, but it can't be experienced by the user. On the other hand, I had forgotten to keep prevent default, I add the equivalent in my code, using `return false;`. BTW, it's needed only because you used `<a>` in your taggables, but I don't see its utility?

Comment: @ValeriuTimbuc Regarding your question about improving your own solution: I agree that having a click event on document only when a content is visible may seem a lighter solution. But you must realize that this method can lead to a lot of events binded and never unbinded, because the user has clicked the toggable itself to close. So in your solution you should do `$document.off()` also in the main `click` part.

Comment: I'm not a fan of return false because it stops propagation, and it's not a good practice. Thanks for your time and suggestions, I really appreciate your input.  I am still not sure which way Im gonna continue, I need to make a few more tests. But probably I will try to improve the event binding/unbinding.

Comment: @ValeriuTimbuc It's actually matter of taste, once sure to have really identified where and what are the possible side effects of this or that solution.